# Bootstrap responsive horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out why the following site starts to show a horizontal scroll bar when it's reduced in browser width.

http://www.woodonwellington.com/

I don't see anything to the right side that should cause this...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right. It should be something like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
   .hide-scrollbar-sm {
      overflow-x: hidden;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `<html style="overflow-x: hidden;">` or do so with a stylesheet. It did work for me and fixed the problem on desktop and mobile!

Comment: How did you determine this given that the question was asked five years ago and linked to a website that quite likely has been changed during that time?

Comment: I just found the question while googling a very similar problem where adjusting body overflow did nothing and thought it could help someone with a similar problem. It is a pretty general solution that should get rid of almost all horizontal scrollbars